# always-use-default-target="false" and default-target-url do not work with spring-social

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-social

always-use-default-target and always-use-default-target="false" works fine if the user logins with username and password

Both attributes seems to be ignored when using spring-social

When the user logins using Facebook or Twitter:

- If the user went to the login page because he/she clicked the "login" button, he/she is redirected to "/" after a successful login. I expected he/she to be redirected to default-target-url
- If the user was redirected to the login page because he/she tried to access a protected url, he/she is also redirected to "/" after a successful login. I expected he/she to be redirected to original protected url he/she requested.

I am using

- spring 3.1.3.RELEASE
- spring security 3.1.3.RELEASE
- spring social 1.0.2.RELEASE

This is my spring-security.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <http use-expressions="true" access-denied-page="/ingresar/?acceso_denegado=true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/signin/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/url1/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/url2/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_XXX')"/>
        ...
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll" />
        <form-login login-page="/url3/" default-target-url="/url4" always-use-default-target="false" 
                    authentication-failure-url="/url5" login-processing-url="/url6"/>
        <logout logout-url="/logout"/>
    </http>    

    <beans:bean id="myUserService" class="my.kalos.service.MyUserServiceImpl"/>

    <beans:bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.password.StandardPasswordEncoder"/>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref='myUserService'>
            <password-encoder ref="encoder"/>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

This is my spring-social config class

```
@Configuration  
public class MyAppSocialConfig {

    @Inject
    MyAppConnectionSignUp myAppConnectionSignUp;

    @Inject
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator() {
        ConnectionFactoryRegistry registry = new ConnectionFactoryRegistry();
        registry.addConnectionFactory(new FacebookConnectionFactory(myAppConf.getFbAppId(), myAppConf.getFbAppSecret()));
        registry.addConnectionFactory(new TwitterConnectionFactory(myAppConf.getTtConsumerKey(), myAppConf.getTtConsumerSecret()));
        return registry;
    }

    @Bean
    public UsersConnectionRepository usersConnectionRepository() {
        JdbcUsersConnectionRepository repository = new JdbcUsersConnectionRepository(dataSource,
                connectionFactoryLocator(), Encryptors.noOpText());
        repository.setConnectionSignUp(myAppConnectionSignUp);
        return repository;
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(value="request", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
    public ConnectionRepository connectionRepository() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        MyUser user = (MyUser) authentication.getPrincipal();
      return usersConnectionRepository().createConnectionRepository(String.valueOf(user.getId()));
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(value="request", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)   
    public Facebook facebook() {
        return connectionRepository().getPrimaryConnection(Facebook.class).getApi();
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(value="request", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)   
    public Twitter twitter() {
        return connectionRepository().getPrimaryConnection(Twitter.class).getApi();
    }

    @Bean
    public ProviderSignInController providerSignInController() {
        ProviderSignInController controller = new MyAppProviderSignInController(...);
        controller.setSignInUrl("/someUrl/");
        return controller;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? An answer would be useful. You could answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

I finally get it to work but I use XML configuration. The idea is to override the default URL ("/") using postLoginUrl property.

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <!-- Enable csrf protection -->
    <csrf />
    <form-login login-page="/sign" default-target-url="/dashboard" authentication-failure-url="/sign" username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password" />
    <!-- Dashboard is protected -->
    <intercept-url pattern="/dashboard**/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <!-- Adds social authentication filter to the Spring Security filter chain. -->
    <custom-filter ref="socialAuthenticationFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
</http>


<!-- Configures the social authentication filter which integrates Spring Social with Spring Security -->
<beans:bean id="socialAuthenticationFilter" class="org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationFilter">
    <beans:constructor-arg index="0" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <beans:constructor-arg index="1" ref="userIdSource" />
    <beans:constructor-arg index="2" ref="usersConnectionRepository" />
    <beans:constructor-arg index="3" ref="connectionFactoryLocator" />
    <!-- Sets the url of the registration - use in case the sign in has failed -->
    <beans:property name="signupUrl" value="/user/register/" />
    <!-- Sets the url of the dashboard - use in case the sign in has succeed -->
    <beans:property name="postLoginUrl" value="/dashboard/" />
</beans:bean>
```